# Bash: passing a symbol by its hex code

Tags: bash

A program needs special symbol as an argument. I pass this symbol by its hex code like:

```
$ program $'\x1A'
```

It works fine.

But when I call the program from a bash script it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
program $'\x1A'
```

Instead of a symbol program gets sting `$'\x1A'`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is /bin/sh?

Comment: shebang needs to be `#!/bin/bash` because `$'..'` is bash specific syntax

Comment: @anubhava, thanks, it's so simple!) But can I use /bin/sh and change `$'...'` to appropriate construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `/bin/sh` only then you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh

# use printf with equivalent octal value
program $(printf '\032')

# alternatively if echo -e is supported then you may use
program $(echo -e '\x1A')

# another option is to use xxd -r
program $(echo '0x41' | xxd -r)

# another option is to use printf if it supports hex
program $(printf '%b' '\x1A')
```

Comment: [POSIX echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) does not support `-e`.  [Dash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), which is a common `/bin/sh`, does not support it either.  Also, [POSIX printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) does not support hex, only octal.

Comment: ok understood. I have added `xxd` option but not sure if that exists on POSIX shell or not.

Comment: `xxd` is external and in Linux it is provided by `vim-common`.

Comment: @anubhava I suggest `printf '\032'`.  Because this is octal, not hex, it is POSIX and therefore should be supported by whatever `/bin/sh` is.  By contrast, neither `echo -e '\x1A'` nor `printf '%b' '\x1A'` are POSIX and neither are supported by `dash` which is the debian/ubuntu `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks @John1024, I have added it in my answer.